# How can I use hex to go back and create a file

Tags: hex, ascii

I have some hex, and I want to recreate the file. I don't know what the file format is. It starts with "6554 6c6c 6d20" so on and so forth. Unfortunately I'm unable to give you the hex, so I would appreciate it if you could give me some ideas as to where to go on from here.

Also when I converted each value from hex to ASCII, it was clearly garbage..

Thanks in Advance.

R.

Answer (score 0):

#### Magic Numbers

You are describing the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), which is a series of bytes that appears at the beginning of a file that uniquely identifies it. Gary Kessler maintains a [curated list](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) of these file signatures. On *nix systems, you can use [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) to identify files.

#### Recreating Files from Hex

Let's get some sample hex by echoing to xxd.

```sh
bash-5.0$ hexstring=$(printf 'Hello World!' | xxd -g 2 | cut -c11-49)
bash-5.0$ echo $hexstring
4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6421
```

To convert back, use `xxd -p -r`:

```sh
bash-5.0$ echo $hexstring | xxd -p -r
Hello World!
```

Here, `-p` prints the result and `-r` does the reverse of what xxd normally does.